# convert html to pdf in android

Tags: android, itext

i want to convert a html file to pdf
my code is

```
Document document = new Document();
boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
} else {
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
}
String file = null;
if (mExternalStorageWriteable) {
    file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/abcd.pdf";
}

document.open();
PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(file));

InputStream is = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/new1.html");

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(is);

PdfImportedPage page;
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, n);
Image instance = Image.getInstance(page);
document.add(instance);

document.close();
Toast.makeText(this, "pdf created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

i have used itextpdf-5.4.3.jar.
while running this code i am getting an exception  "PDF header signature not found"
...can any one help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to read HTML file as a PDF document using the `PdfReader`.

You could take a look at the [HtmlMovies1](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=55) example from the "iText in Action" book which uses a deprecated `HTMLWorker` for HTML to PDF conversion or take a look at the API documentation of the new [XML Worker](http://api.itextpdf.com/xml/) project.

Answer (score 5):

This [class](https://github.com/blink22/react-native-html-to-pdf/blob/master/android/src/main/java/android/print/PdfConverter.java) works independent of iText.
But to compile, it must be in package ".../java/android/print/"

Here is a simple code example :

```
PdfConverter converter = PdfConverter.getInstance();
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "file.pdf");
String htmlString = "<html><body><p>WHITE (default)</p></body></html>";
converter.convert(getContext(), htmlString, file);
// By now the pdf has been printed in the file.
```